# sizeof Function not Working in Function

Tags: c++, arrays

When I run this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void PrintLengthOfArray(double arr[])
{
  int total_bytes = sizeof(arr);
  int data_type_bytes = sizeof(arr[0]);
  int length = total_bytes / data_type_bytes;

  cout << "method 2: \n";
  cout << "total_bytes = " << total_bytes << "\n";
  cout << "data_type_bytes = " << data_type_bytes << "\n";
  cout << "length = " << length << "\n";
}

int main()
{
  double arr[3] = {1,2,3};
  int total_bytes = sizeof(arr);
  int data_type_bytes = sizeof(arr[0]);
  int length = total_bytes / data_type_bytes;

  // first method
  cout << "method 1: \n";
  cout << "total_bytes = " << total_bytes << "\n";
  cout << "data_type_bytes = " << data_type_bytes << "\n";
  cout << "length = " << length << "\n\n";

  // second method
  PrintLengthOfArray(arr);
}
```

I get:

```
method 1: 
total_bytes = 24
data_type_bytes = 8
length = 3

method 2: 
total_bytes = 8
data_type_bytes = 8
length = 1
```

That is, it's like the `total_bytes = sizeof(arr)` statement in the function is only computing the size of an individual element, or just `arr[0]`.  What's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the second method, you pass the array by value to your function. It decays to a pointer, hence the size is that of the pointer, in your case 8 bytes. Note that a function declaration

```
f(double arr[])
```

or even

```
f(double arr[3])
```

is translated by the compiler into

```
f(double*)
```

The only meaningful way of passing an array to a function and retaining its size is to pass by reference, e.g.

```
void f(double (&arr)[3]) 
{
    std::cout << sizeof arr << std::endl; // displays 3 * sizeof(double)
}
```

In case you want to be able to pass arbitrary-length arrays, I recommend passing by reference via a templated function:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void f(T (&arr)[N])
{
    // N gives you the size in the body
}
```

If you still want to pass by value, then the only way of "detecting" its size is to pass an additional parameter to your function that represents the size of the array. However this may give rise to lots of headaches, and it is prone to errors. You are probably better with [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

Comment: I think it is equally important to point out the function parameter is adjusted into a pointer.

Comment: @vsoftco Okay, that makes sense.  Is there a standard way of checking the size of an array in a function?

Comment: @bcf Not if you pass it by value. The only way is to pass by reference, see the edit.

Comment: @NickyC Not sure I understand exactly what you mean. I mentioned "decayed" into a pointer, are you thinking of something else?

Comment: @vsoftco http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515366/size-of-object-passed-to-function

Comment: @vsoftco The decay at the function call is caused by the fact that the function parameter is a pointer. The function parameter is a pointer because the array as a parameter is adjusted.

Comment: @vsoftco Thanks.  Is that template method common?  Or, do most practitioners just use STL types and algorithms now?  I don't think I've seen that template method used in such a way.

Comment: @bcf I'd stick with standard containers. I've seen the template trick in case you don't (can't) use the standard library containers, or in the case you deal with legacy code.